# Proportional weighting of proportions

Tags: proportion, weights, weighted-mean

I apologize for the horrific title, but I can't accurately express what I want to ask. If I have eight observations with two groups with each observation having a `numerator` and `denominator` values, the `result` variable is simply `numerator / denominator`:

```
name  group numerator denominator result
A         1        12          34  0.353
B         1        15          40  0.375
C         1        10          20  0.5  
D         1      1000        1200  0.833
E         2       120         150  0.8  
F         2        80         100  0.8  
G         2       150         200  0.75 
H         2       130         150  0.867
```

I am interested in the group means of the `result`:

```
group group_mean
    1      0.515
    2      0.804
```

However, in this scenario, observations `A`, `B`, and `C` are clearly driving the mean of `group 1` down, even though observation `D` should clearly have more weight than the other ones. How should I correctly weight observations is this scenario? This seems like such a straightforward thing, but the fact that `result` is already a proportion, I'm having a difficulty figuring out the correct way of doing it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for frequency weights. You should be weighting by denominator. (You can also use sampling weights - this will give the same mean). Most software has this function.

One easy way to do this is to calculate group_mean as sum(numerator) / sum(denominator).

A second way, if you already have the result column is to calculate sum(result * denominator) / sum(denominator).